# Wired fire/smoke alarms not communicating with each other

Tags: electrical, smoke-detectors

After replacing the wired fire alarms in my house with new ones, when testing any of them, that one beeps but not the others.

Model is BRK First Alert 9120B6CP.

Each alarm came with three cables. Black and white for  power, and orange for sending the signal that should cause all of them to go off when one of them does.

I have verified they are all properly wired and that they all have power (green light is on for all).

Any ideas on what else to check or verify to have them all communicate?

Comment: Manufacturer/model #?

Comment: I just added to the post, @manassehkatz. Thanks for pointing out it was missing.

Comment: Are all of the alarms the same model?  Mixing models can cause problems like this.

Comment: Did the previous alarms communicate with each other successfully?

Comment: IIRC, Last time I tested them (about a year ago) they communicated with each other. When I tested them again they were not doing it anymore. Of the previous ones I had, one was older. Changed that one and they still weren't working. So I went ahead and changed them all (even most were only 4 years old) to the same newer model. Still nothing. I'm stumped.

Comment: Could there be another that you haven’t found yet?

Comment: I've looked again in the basement and the garage, just in case. Couldn't find any other. Unless they hid one in the attic (which I don't think they'd do), there don't seem to be any others...

Comment: If you turn the breaker for the smokes off, connect a 9V battery between the orange and white wires (+ to orange, - to white) and then turn the breaker for the smokes back on, do they all sound?

Comment: I'll test it today. Should I test all of them to see if it works with or just one?

Comment: Could the interconnect work only when actual smoke is detected, and not work when the Test button is pushed, in order to allow you to test only the one individual alarm at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a short-circuit. The cable connecting one of the alarms in the basement had been trapped by the electrical box cover. The cover is metallic, and had cut into the plastic enough to make contact.

**To find the issue** I turned off the breaker, disconnected the signal cable from all of them, and started testing them from the top of the house using a **9V battery**, as mentioned in one of the comments (+ to orange, - to white). Started with two, verified it was working, and kept going connecting alarms to be signal cable until I found out the culprit. After detailed inspection of the one that was causing the issue I noticed the cable damage.

Thank you @ThreePhaseEel for the 9V battery trick. It was really useful.